# Сортировка в Pandas по абсолютным значениям

Tags: python, сортировка, pandas, dataframe

Есть столбец в `dataframe`.

Как отсортировать весь `dataframe` по абсолютным значениям этого столбца, без `reindex` и `iloc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [83]: np.random.seed((3, 1415))

In [84]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(10, 2)), columns=["a","b"])

In [85]: df
Out[85]:
    a   b
0 -89  -2
1  23 -10
2  43  26
3 -45  41
4  39  41
5  54  15
6 -37   4
7  28  20
8  72  82
9  -4 -66
```

Решение:

```
In [86]: res = df.assign(x=df["a"].abs()).sort_values("x").drop(columns="x")
```

Результат:

```
In [87]: res
Out[87]:
    a   b
9  -4 -66
1  23 -10
7  28  20
6 -37   4
4  39  41
2  43  26
3 -45  41
5  54  15
8  72  82
0 -89  -2
```

Comment: А можно без создания нового столбца?

Comment: @user358441, может и можно, но я привел, по-моему, наиболее идиоматичный способ